# Cast generic Collection to List once, then RemoveAt multiple times

Tags: c#, .net, casting

I have a generic collection of objects as a property of an object. This data comes from a sql query and api. I want to use the RemoveAt method to remove some of them efficiently. But Visual Studio complains to me that the RemoveAt method is undefined. My intuition is to cast the Collection to a List, giving me access to the RemoveAt method. I only want to cast one time, then use RemoveAt as many times as necessary. I could use the Remove(object) command, but it requires traversing the Collection to look for the object for each call, which is slower than using RemoveAt

Here is what I'm trying:

```
obj.stuckArray = obj.stuckArray.ToList();
```

After this line, I have a line of code that looks like this:

```
obj.stuckArray.RemoveAt(1);
```

Unfortunately the `RemoveAt` gets underlined with red and the warning from Visual Studio reads: "ICollection does not contain a definition for 'RemoveAt'"

Is it possible to cast once and RemoveAt multiple? Or is this not possible?

Comment: You can´t change the type of a member. Define a new property of type `List<MyType>` instead. However if `obj.stuckArray` already *is* an `ICollection`, it should work anyway, as `List<T>` implements `ICollection`. So please show how `stuckArray` is defined.

Comment: Just create a new variable that is type List, so `List<someType> someList = obj.stuckArray.ToList();`

Comment: I've done both of these things. No luck. It might be a code sense issue. Let me update the question.

Comment: With an `ICollection` you'll need to loop through the list once and add each item to be deleted to a new `List`; then loop through the new `List` and call `.Remove(obj)` on the `ICollection`. See [ICollection on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info on the available members.

Comment: I really don't want to use Remove since it has to traverse the entire collection to find the object. That's the whole reason I'm using RemoveAt. This is for a web api and I need it to be as fast as possible.

Comment: Very confusing - do you want to: remove elements from copy and keep original untouched, remove elements from original and keep copy untouched, remove elements from both at the same time, something else?

Comment: Can you change the object that holds `stuckArrary`?

Comment: Can you change the `ICollection<something> stuckArray` to be an `IList<something> stuckArray`?  That way you can call `RemoveAt()` and all the other `IList` methods as you like.

@ZoharPeled You just beat me to it.

Comment: I want to change the type to List, then use RemoveAt multiple times.

Comment: Note that if you want to remove multiple items (comparable to total count) you'd be way better off copying items that need to stay to new arrays than remove items one by one - see HimBromBeere answer for explanations of O(n^2) behavior due to copy on remove if you need to remove let's say half of the items.

Comment: Very sad to see that the question gets downvoted and closevoted by so many people before I can make the appropriate edits. I can't keep up. I'll try to figure it out some other way.

Comment: You can edit the question even if it gets downvoted or even closed. That´s the entire point why it´s called "on hold": To make it possible to the OP to *improve* the answer. When the question is clear enough it can be re-opened and answered. Just for clarification, I did neither of those.

Comment: @toshiomagic you have given us all conflicting comments, first you want to convert to List, then you dont because you are prematurely concerned about performance, then 12 minutes ago you want it to be a List again.  You _really_ have to clarify what you are asking.  You _should_ have asked a clear question to begin with.  Since you have a question that is confusing and otherwise unanswerable without your edits, what do you think would happen?  Its going to be put on hold until it can become an answerable question.

Comment: I never said I didn't want it to be a list. I said I didn't want to cast as a List _multiple_ times.

Comment: You mix *casting* with *converting*. I suppose you don´t wont to call `ToList` multiple times, which is a *conversion*. While the former is usually quite fast, the latter may take some time. So see my answer for what to do.

Comment: I figured it out. Instead of doing the casting over and over again inside a loop with the RemoveAt command, I've just stored the indexes I want to remove in an array, sorted it descending, and in another loop cast once and remove array.Count.

Comment: Feel free to add an answer to your own question. Otherwise accept an existing one.

Answer (score 2):

Just do it in three statements instead of two, using a local variable:

```
var list = obj.stuckArray.ToList();
list.RemoveAt(1);
obj.stuckArray = list;
```

That way the type of `stuckArray` doesn't matter as much: you only need to be able to call `ToList()` on it. The `RemoveAt` method on `List<T>` is fine because that's the type of `list`.

Comment: This seems computationally undesirable. I have to cast my array as a list every time I want to remove an element. Would it be faster to just use Remove? I was hoping to be able to cast the array to a list a single time.

Comment: @toshiomagic: I was basing my answer on what you were trying already. I assumed you *wanted* to take a copy. (After all, there could be references to the collection already somewhere else.) If you want to modify the collection in place, please update your question with more requirements. (Any reason the type has to be `ICollection<T>` to start wit rather than `IList<T>` for example?)

Comment: @toshiomagic Again: [premature optimzation is the root of all evil](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization). Are you sure, that calling `ToList` will affect your overall performance that much? Did you *measure* this?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you want to remove an element from the array and store it back into the original member `stuckArray`. However as an `Icollection` has no method `RemoveAt` defined, you get the error. The method however exists on `List<T>`.

So do the following instead:

```
var tmp = obj.stuckArray.ToList();
tmp.RemoveAt(1);
obj.stuckArray = tmp;
```

However this will traverse the entire collection anyway, as `ToList` will copy the entire collection into a new one. But I don´t see any way around this in order to delete an element from your array, because an array has no `RemoveAt`-method.

As per your EDIT: why not just make the `Remove` *after* the re-definition of your `stuckArray`:

```
var tmp = obj.stuckArray.ToList();
obj.stuckArray = tmp;
```

Now you can call `RemoveAt` as often as you want:

```
((List<MyType>)obj.stuckArray).RemoveAt(1);
((List<MyType>)obj.stuckArray).RemoveAt(1);
((List<MyType>)obj.stuckArray).RemoveAt(1);
```

Casting this so many times shouldn´t have a big impact on your performance, as `obj.stuckArray` already *is*  a `List<MyType>`. `RemoveAt` on the other hand  will have an effect here, as the method will copy the internal array, as you can see at the [source-code for `RemoveAt`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,3d46113cc199059a):

```
public void RemoveAt(int index) {
    if ((uint)index >= (uint)_size) {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
    Contract.EndContractBlock();
    _size--;
    if (index < _size) {
        Array.Copy(_items, index + 1, _items, index, _size - index); // here the entire array will be traversed again
    }
    _items[_size] = default(T);
    _version++;
}
```

So by calling `RemoveAt` three times, you also copy the internal array three times.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the object that exposes the `struckArray` property,
you can expose `stuckArray` as `ICollection<T>`, but inside the object use a `List<T>` as it's backing field. Then you can add a method that removes an item by it's index:

```
class MyClass
{
     private list<int> _stuckArray; // of course, this doesn't have to be int...

     public ICollection<int> StuckArray {get {return _stuckArray;}}

     public RemoveFromStuckArray(int index)
     {
          _stuckArray.RemoveAt(index);
     }
}
```

That will enable you to keep whatever references you already have to the property, and also supply a method to remove items by their indexes efficiently, though I'm not sure that's such a good idea to enable removing items by indexes from an `ICollection` in the first place.